# Calculating arc length based on certain parameters

Tags: calculus

For a smooth curve that passes twice through the origin, where arc length, points p1 & p2 & their tangents are known, is it possible to calculate partial arc lengths (ie, p1 to origin, central loop, and origin to p2)?

[image]

Comment: If tangents are known for different arcs cant we find the function using integration.

Comment: Not without more information, unless I'm missing something, there are infinitely many curves with the given parameters.

Comment: @Travis If the curve takes the shortest path between points or given arc length (ie curve of minimal energy), surely there are not infinitely many curves?

Comment: Could you give more information about the context ?

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici basically, I have a collection of curves, and for argument's sake, let's say the equations for which are unknown. The points where it passes though the origin are fairly straightforward to find with a root search, but intuitively, if a smooth (ie infinitely differentiable) curve with a given arc length passes between two points, surely it should be possible to interpolate between the two an mimic the original curve fairly accurately?

Comment: For argument's sake, lets say the curve is something along the lines of `b = 0.84; a = 1; c = 0.001; ParametricPlot[{c (a/2 + b Cos[t] + a/2 Cos [2 t]) Log[t^2]!, c (b Sin[t] + a/2 Sin[2 t]) Log[t^2]!}, {t , 9 Pi/2, 11 Pi/2}]`

Comment: @martin There is no shortest curve with the given parameters. Also, we could always deform the curve by keeping the arc length constant and increasing/decreasing size of the loop.

Comment: @Travis, if curvature didn't make any draramatic changes, surely the size of the loop would be estimable?

Comment: @Travis, presuming the curve had similar curvature to limaçon, with only major difference being a some function (eg log t) being applied to x & y of the parametric.

Comment: @Travis, re there is no shortest curve. Note arc length is fixed & known. There should be a path that the curve should take that would expend least energy, no?

Comment: @martin Yes, surely we could turn bounds on curvature into a lower bound on the loop length.

Comment: @martin It would be helpful if you were more specific about the class of curves you want to consider. "Similar curvature to a limacon and with some function applied to the parametric components" could mean many different things depending on the intended meaning of "similar" and "applied".

Comment: @Travis How would we go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you could draw this curve as $(x(t), y(t))$, and the length of the curve would be $$\int \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt$$

Comment: yes, but without a root search, points where it passes through the origin are unknown.

Comment: Ok, nut how did you do that in your example?

Comment: the example given is a trivial case